# Was it illegal in 18th century France or Spain to use false titles of nobility?

Tags: 18th-century, nobility

> The friend of popes and kings and noblemen, and of all the male and female ruffians and vagabonds of Europe, abbé, soldier, charlatan, gamester, financier, diplomatist, viveur, philosopher, virtuoso, “chemist, fiddler, and buffoon,” each of these, and all of these was Giacomo Casanova, **Chevalier de Seingalt**, Knight of the Golden Spur.

In 1760, in Switzerland, Giacomo Casanova used for the first time the title of "Chevalier de Seingalt".
Source: Masters, John (1969). Casanova. [p.145]  New York: Bernard Geis Associates. ISBN 978-0-7181-0570-9. OCLC 570359581 – via Internet Archive.
Original [here](https://openlibrary.org/works/OL123578W/Casanova)

I have read Casanova's Memoirs ([here](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2981) on Project Gutemberg, in English) and I see no mention in them of his self-appointed title of "Chevalier de Seingalt". So also no consideration by him about possible retribution by the law.
He also used the title of baron or count of Farussi (the maiden name of his mother).

In the Memoirs is also pretty clear that he was not alone in this habit. He routinely meets with 'counts' which are for the most part adventurers and knaves.

To note that in his Memoirs Casanova recalls one episode: in 1767 he was detained in Spain and the local official

> told me to write my name, profession, and business in Spain in Italian. I could not refuse him this pleasure, so I wrote as follows:
> “My name is Jacques Casanova; I am a subject of the Republic of Venice, by profession a man of letters, and in rank a Knight of the Golden Spur. [...]"

He was truly ensigned with the Golden Spur by the Pope but I notice he did not mention the title of "Chevalier de Seingalt" in an official written statement.

My question is: was it illegal in Casanova's time (18th century) in France or Spain to introduce oneself using a false noble title?

Please note that am not asking about the likelyhood of the retribution by the law. As that would depend on the connections and possible patronage enjoyed by the offender.

Comment: I'd imagine that there was a difference between adopting a title of your own invention and fraudulently passing yourself off using someone else's title. Also, knights are not nobles.

Comment: @ Steve bird  In British law, everyone except for the Monarch and a few hundred titled peers is a commoner.  That includes the close family members of the monarch and the peers.  In contrast, in continental Eruope, the nobles were a much larger social class than in Britain.  Many nobles were untitled, so being made a knight was a step up for many untitled nobles.

Comment: There was also a good answer regarding Spanish law but unfortunately has been deleted. In short it would have been illegal to officially state a noble title in Spain at the time. Which may be the reason why Casanova omitted it on the occasion in OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding France, using a self-assigned title of "Chevalier" was formally impermissible at the time, although it would have been acceptable in prior centuries. Originally, noble titles were a matter of pure custom, especially for the most ancient families who could not point even in principle to a specific document granting the title. As the centralised monarchy exerted its growing authority, it eventually developed a monopoly on the creation of noble titles. Casanova lived in a time when this had been formally established by the crown.

Royal control was motivated not only by the evident political advantages of being able to dispense patronage, but because nobles were immune from an important tax, *la taille*. (This is simplifying a complex set of rules but is essentially true; see chapter 6 of *Fiscal Crises, Liberty and Representative Government, 1450-1789*, ed. Philip Hoffman and Kathryn Norberg; Stanford, 1994). Therefore, various royal ordinances set out to force purported nobles to prove their nobility, and there were several rounds of active investigation in the seventeenth century and up to the Revolution (see the entry for *Anoblissement* in *Dictionnaire de l'Ancien Régime* by Anne Conchon, Bruno Maes and Isabelle Paresys; Armand Colin, 2014). Chevalier is not a noble title as such, and did not grant the same privileges, but it is in the same category of titles that the crown sought to control.

In the case of the lower title "chevalier", I think the first formal sanction is from Louis XIII in the "Code Michau", a long edict of 1629. Its [article 189](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/LA_GRANDE_CONFERENCE_DES_ORDONNANCES_ET/DU3t5p9HfqcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA387&printsec=frontcover) reads in part:

> Nous défendons [...] à toutes personnes de prendre qualité de Chevalier, s'ils ne l'ont obtenu de nos predecesseurs ou de Nous, ou que l'eminence de leur qualité ne la leur attribuë. Enjoignons à tous nos Juges de leur en interdire l'usage & faire soigneusement observer lesdites Ordonnances.

He also decrees in article 194 that the knightly orders of Saint Michael and of the Holy Spirit are reserved for qualified people of noble ancestry. By this edict, you cannot call yourself Chevalier unless by grant of the king or a predecessor. The title was (in most cases) not an inheritable one, though it was fairly frequently given. Knightly titles were commonly sought by members of noble families who had no higher title, and were also awarded on merit to holders of important offices and so forth. In some regions, such as Brittany, it was automatically available to all titled nobles and their eldest sons - another example of the complex web of local privileges under the law of the ancien regime.

If we can regard Casanova's title as French at all (having invented it, it's not clear if he invented it *as a French title* or from some other polity) then he might be making himself legally answerable. The same goes for higher titles such as *baron* or *comte*, and especially if he tried to exert privileges of the nobility.